# SQL Server - Group by Values from Different Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a set of data like this:

```
   ID   Person1   Value1   Person2   Value2   Person3   Value3   Period
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1       A        1         D        1                          June
   2       B        2                                             July
   3       C        3                                             June
   4       B        1         C        3         A        2       August
   5       C        2         A        2                          June
```

Column ID is just a row identifier and doesn't mean anything. I want to group them by Person and Period and followed by the sum of each person's value. The expected result would look like:

```
Person   Period   Value
-----------------------
   A      June      3
   A      August    2
   B      July      2
   B      August    1
   C      June      5
   C      August    3
   D      June      1
```

Is it doable? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No it is not doable... you have found a problem that is not solvable!  :D

Comment: That would be very unfortunate. @Hogan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Based on question edit and comment:

```
SELECT Person, Period, SUM(Val) as total
FROM (
  SELECT Person1 as Person, Period, Value1 as Val
  FROM tablename
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Person2 as Person, Period, Value2 as Val
  FROM tablename
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Person3 as Person, Period, Value3 as Val
  FROM tablename
) sub
GROUP BY Person, Period
```

---

> Original answer

Reduce the problem to steps to solve.

First Normalize

```
SELECT Person1 as Person, Value1 as Val
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT Person2 as Person, Value2 as Val
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT Person3 as Person, Value3 as Val
FROM tablename
```

Then add em up with group by like normal

```
SELECT Person, SUM(Val) as total
FROM (
  SELECT Person1 as Person, Value1 as Val
  FROM tablename
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Person2 as Person, Value2 as Val
  FROM tablename
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Person3 as Person, Value3 as Val
  FROM tablename
) sub
GROUP BY Person
```

Comment: I edited the question a little bit. Definitely not easier. Thanks for your help. @Hogan

Comment: ok @Reb.Z -- I'll answer that but it is really easy based on what I showed you.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Hogan

Comment: After trying and testing with different datasets, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! @Hogan

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `apply` for this purpose:

```
select v.person, v.period, sum(v.value)
from t apply
     (values (Person1, Value1, Period),
             (Person2, Value2, Period),
             (Person3, Value3, Period)
     ) v(Person, Value, Period)
group by v.person, v.period;
```

Comment: What about Person3 and Value3?

Comment: @Hogan . . . I think the code generalizes pretty easily ;)  Actually, I just missed them when I first read the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE (Person , Val) AS (SELECT Person1 as Person, Value1 as Val FROM          tablename UNION ALL SELECT Person2 as Person, Value2 as Val FROM tablename UNION ALL SELECT Person3 as Person, Value3 as Val FROM tablename ) SELECT Person, SUM(Val) FROM CTE GROUP BY Person
```